# nlinfit Dimension Error

Tags: matlab, non-linear-regression

I am using nonlinearfit tool in matlab.
I keep getting the following error:

> Error using nlinfit (line 210)
>   MODELFUN must be a function that returns a vector of fitted values the same size as Y (1-by-100).  The model function you provided returned a result that was 1-by-2.
>   One common reason for a size mismatch is using matrix operators (*, /, ^) in your function instead of the corresponding element-wise operators (.*, ./, .^).

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098704/matlab-error-using-nlinfit) very similar to mine, but still I get the same error. I have tried calculating **myfun** on the console while using a vector as an input, which gives me output of correct dimension. It will be ton of help if anybody can point out the mistake.

```
% Defining the function
myfun = @(t,b)exp(t.*b(1)+b(2));
[y_a] = arrayfun(myfun,x_a);
% Using nonlinear least square minimization
beta0 = [1 1];
nlinfit(x,y,myfun, beta0)
```

Thanks in advance...:)

Edit: Found this to be working.
    `g = fittype('exp(k*x + a)');`
    `[fit1,gof,fitinfo] = fit(x',y',g,'StartPoint',[1 1]);`

Answer (score 0):

The function used in [nlinfit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop) takes the parameter vector as its first argument, then the independent data vector.  You want,

`myfun = @(b,t)exp(t.*b(1)+b(2));`

Note that you could just use `*` rather than `.*` in this instance too.

Comment: What are your dimensions of `x` and `y`, and what error message do you get when the inputs to `myfun` correctly ordered?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have already tried it. I tried something like.
`myfun = @(b,t)exp(t*b(1));`
Even that simple function was giving me the same error.

Also tried lsqcurvefit, got very much the same error.

finally managed to get around it by using simple fit function.

`g = fittype('exp(k*x + a)');
[fit1,gof,fitinfo] = fit(x',y',g,'StartPoint',[1 1]);`

Not really sure what the problem was, but any insights will be cool!

Comment: The dimension of x = (1x100) and y = (1x100).
I even tried transposing them into vectors, but didn't get any results.

Comment: Strange, as `x=1:100;y=x+randn(size(x));nlinfit(x,y,myfun,[0 0])` works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment:
Tried changing it, but got the same msg



**MODELFUN must be a function that returns a vector of fitted values the same size as Y
(1-by-100).  The model function you provided returned a result that was 1-by-2.

One common reason for a size mismatch is using matrix operators (*, /, ^) in your function
instead of the corresponding elementwise operators (.*, ./, .^).**

I am not sure may some problem with the matlab version I have installed.